# is it possible to fill the circle by degrees in android?

Tags: android

is it possbile to fill the circle to some degrees i.e(90 or 270 etc).

thankx

Answer (score 3):

Yes,
As a support you can refer to [this](http://www.anddev.org/the_pizza_timer_-_threading-drawing_on_canvas-t126.html) program which try to implement something like which you want.

Happy Programming!

Answer (score 1):

if you're talking about Canvas drawing, see [`Canvas.drawArc()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawArc%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)

Comment: There's a sample in the Android API Demos showing how to use drawArc to get different results; http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Arcs.html

Answer (score 1):

If you mean drawing something like a slice of pie, you can use [ArcShape](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/ArcShape.html)